# How do you debug Jenkins Multibranch scan - not processing new branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a multibranch pipeline project in Jenkins.  I have had two main branches (master and production) running for some time correctly.  But one of the steps is to build a new version of `node` docker image (on a slave Raspberry pi) for the ultimate base for the production system. I felt it would be better to isolate that step in its own branch so that we can control when we upgrade the version.

So I made a branch off master called "node" and altered the `Jenkinsfile` to just have the step that build node in it. I also upped the version of node it was to build (to 7.10.0).

Multibranch indexing finds the new branch, but then does nothing with it. How do I find out why?

Here is the output from the scan/indexing run

```
Started by timer
[Sun May 07 21:43:00 BST 2017] Starting branch indexing...
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to alan@kanga.home:dev/pasv5
 > git config remote.origin.url alan@kanga.home:dev/pasv5 # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote alan@kanga.home:dev/pasv5 # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to alan@kanga.home:dev/pasv5
 > git config remote.origin.url alan@kanga.home:dev/pasv5 # timeout=10
Fetching & pruning origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
Getting remote branches...
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen branch in repository origin/node
Seen branch in repository origin/production
Seen 3 remote branches
Checking branch master
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
Met criteria
No changes detected: master (still at 8c4fddfa66f26af0089f0e55afcd2ac9e13152ef)
Checking branch production
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
Met criteria
No changes detected: production (still at fa97e2fd76895c958a484b21fb4d4852ad000c9b)
Checking branch node
Done.
[Sun May 07 21:43:01 BST 2017] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.27 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Note on `master` and `production` it notes `Jenkinsfile` found, but on `node` it doesn't.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

My fault - under the "Advanced" options in the project configuration of git, you can list the branches to consider.  I had put in there `master` and `production` and not `node`.  As soon as I changed that, it started processing the new branch.